# How to add some text in a plot_ly densitymapbox

Tags: r

I can't make plot_ly display the text I want when I create a densitymapbox.

I ran into the following problem with plot_ly densitimapboxes in R.

```
library(plotly)

#quakes = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/earthquakes-23k.csv')
test_df = data.frame(Adress = c("Adress A", "Adress B", "Adress C", "Adress D"),
                     Latitude = c(47, 48, 47, 48),
                     Longitude = c(15, 15, 16, 16),
                     Magnitude = c(5000, 5000, 50000, 50000000))

fig <- test_df 
fig <- fig %>%
  plot_ly(
    type = "densitymapbox",
    hovertext = text,
    text = ~Adress,
    lat = ~Latitude,
    lon = ~Longitude,
    z = ~log(Magnitude),
    zauto = TRUE,
    coloraxis = "coloraxis",
    radius = 5)
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    mapbox = list(
      style = "stamen-toner",#stamen-terrain",
      center = list(lon = 16, lat = 47),
      zoom = 5
      ),
    coloraxis = list(colorscale = "Viridis")
    )

fig
```

If you execute the above code and then hover over one of the points, the z value (in this case log(Magnitude)) and the coordinates will be displayed. My question is: how do I display a different text, for instance the adress reported in the test dataframe test_df, when i hover over the Data points on the map? So far I tried using hoverinfo and hovertext, but they don't seem to work.

Additional and only marginal question: is there a way to make the points with low magnitude less blurry (and the with the lowest magnitude visible at all) without removing the weights?